# I Added 4 action bar icon using action bar sherlock but it was all align to the right with some space on the left

Tags: android

So my question is How do I make the 4 icon I have made align spreadly on my action bar? I can't use the cheat way like styling the home icon into the 1st icon because I have done that on my another actionbar but my application have 2 action bar and i am styling the second so how can I do out where my ActionBar does not have gap on the left.

A screenshot of my project actionbar

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yskQCrUluU4/UmoOBn1jKPI/AAAAAAAAAOc/qEd8aF4dgVk/s1600/Screenshot_2013-10-25-14-19-02.png

I have tried this but doesn't work as it still have some spaces on the left where the icon and title is

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.realback);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
```

on my res/main/menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/github1" 
    android:icon="@drawable/back" 
    android:showAsAction="always"
     android:title="@string/setting_label"
    android:titleCondensed="@string/settings" 
    android:visible="true"></item>

    <item android:id="@+id/github2" 
    android:icon="@drawable/like" 
    android:showAsAction="always"
     android:title="@string/setting_label"
    android:titleCondensed="@string/settings" 
    android:visible="true"></item>


     <item android:id="@+id/github3" 
    android:icon="@drawable/comment" 
    android:showAsAction="always"
     android:title="@string/setting_label"
    android:titleCondensed="@string/settings" 
    android:visible="true"></item>


     <item android:id="@+id/github4" 
    android:icon="@drawable/menu" 
    android:showAsAction="always"
     android:title="@string/setting_label"
    android:titleCondensed="@string/settings" 
    android:visible="true"></item>



    </menu>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 2 Action Bar?

Comment: Means my program use 2 action bar the 1st action bar have only 2 icons and the 2nd action bar have 4 icons

Comment: I think you are trying to have Split Action Bar? (In simpler term, one bar is at top and another is at bottom), is it the case?

Comment: nope both bar is on top 2 different action bar for different activities in a program

Comment: Example i have 2 baseactivity, the 1st baseactivity i have 2 icons only for the actionbar. and the 2nd baseactivity2 i have 4 icons. So when my activity need 2 icon action bar it will extend baseactivity if my activity need 4 icon action bar it will extend baeactivity2

Comment: Then take flag in your BaseActivity and according to the Flag value, inflate the particular menu file.

Comment: I have googled flag value and i still don't understand how to do it, do you have any tutorials/guides i can follow? thanksss